How to use falco driver for rocky linux since there is no prebuild driver for rocky linux
I want to install falco on my kubernetes cluster with helm. I want to use ebpf probe.  My kernel is       4.18.0-513.24.1.el8_9.x86_64 and
NAME="Rocky Linux" VERSION="8.9 (Green Obsidian)" ID="rocky" ID_LIKE="rhel centos fedora" VERSION_ID="8.9"
Unfortunately, there is no prebuilt driver for this rocky and my kernel does not support modern ebpf .  How can I build a driver and install galco with helm. I dont want to upgrade my kernel right now.
I tried to use driverkit and run this command driverkit kubernetes -c rocky.yaml and my rocky yaml is:
kernelrelease: 4.18.0-513.24.1.el8_9.x86_64 target: rocky output: module: /tmp/falco_almalinux_4.18.0-513.24.1.el8_9.x86_64_1.ko probe: /tmp/falco_almalinux_4.18.0-513.24.1.el8_9.x86_64_1.o driverversion: master
It generated falco_almalinux_4.18.0-513.24.1.el8_9.x86_64_1.o and falco_almalinux_4.18.0-513.24.1.el8_9.x86_64_1.ko but I dont know how to move forward.
